# Password protect against edit and copy a PDF document

Tags: pdf, applescript, password-protection

I need to password protect a PDF document against editing (not for opening) using AppleScript. A Mac compatible terminal command would be fine too, or if nothing else an app I can call from AppleScript which has this feature in it's dictionary.

Comment: "password protect a pdf against editing" FYI this PDF ISO feature is really just smoke and mirrors, and is not enforced by the PDF file at all, and instead has to be enforced by the PDF application. So this would prevent editing in Adobe, but not in many other viewers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the third-party *command line tool*, `cpdf`.

Have a look at: [Coherent PDF Command Line Tools Community Release](http://community.coherentpdf.com/)

- [Download pre-built cpdf tool](https://github.com/coherentgraphics/cpdf-binaries/archive/master.zip) (This is a direct download link. Building from source is available from link on main page linked above.)
- A comprehensive user manual for the PDF tools can be found as a [PDF document](http://www.coherentpdf.com/cpdfmanual.pdf), or [browsable online](http://www.coherentpdf.com/cpdfmanual/cpdfmanual.html).
- **Note:** the **Community Release** version of **Coherent PDF Command Line Tools** is **free**.

---

<sup>Note that I'm not affiliated with this product, only a satisfied user.</sup>